# htaccess rewrite rule to Wordpress page without changing URL

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a rewrite rule in my .htaccess file:
(/.htaccess)

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^wptest$ ./wp/main/ [L,R]
```

I've tried lots of combinations of different switches here, no R, P, OR etc, most caused problems.

The Wordpress htaccess file is untouched:
(/wp/.htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
```

When I enter:

```
{domain}/wptest
```

The browser resolves to:

```
{domain}/wp/main
```

but always changes the URL to:  /wp/main.

The file structure is:

/.htaccess
/wp/.htaccess

(there is no file or directory /wp/main - this is the Wordpress page stub)

How can I prevent the Wordpress htaccess from changing the URL - ie going to the Wordpress page "main", but leaving the URL as /wptest?

Comment: Try and change `[L,R]` to just `[L]`. The `R` flag means "redirect" (which is the opposite of what you want). [Here's the manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html)

Comment: Thanks Magnus. I've tried this, using Fiddler I can see that when I use [L,R] I get:    /wptest -> /wp/main      When I take the R out, I get:   /wptest -> /wp  - so the main page doesn't load - an empty page loads instead.

Comment: Please show us your file structure with the relevant files and folders.

Comment: Hi Magnus, is what I've added to the question enough?